# How to display custom data points along the x-axis in Octave?

Tags: octave

I want to plot a vector of length 7 against a a vector also of length 7 with values [697    770    852    941   1209   1336   1477]

I want to display the values [697    770    852    941   1209   1336   1477] along the x-axis at the respective data points.

How to do this in Octave using `stem` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set(gca(),'xtick',[697,770,852,941,1209,1336,1477])
 set(gca(),'xticklabel',{'697','770','852','941','1209','1336','1477'})`

These two lines of code solved it... :|